# Difficulties in importing ADF projects(10.1.2) in JDeveloper 10g 10.1.2

Tags: oracle-adf

I am Mayuresh and new to ADF technology. Currently I am working on project based on ADF technology. Our source code was previously developed in 10g 10.1.2 version and now we are trying it to import it on our machine. We are also using same JDeveloper (10g 10.1.2) but after opening .JWS file in JDeveloper only structure appears i.e.

> Application Name
>   Project 1
>   Project 2
>   Project 3

nothing inside it. we have gone through many sites for help but still not able to import our source code successfully in JDeveloper 10g 10.1.2

If anyone can help us out then that will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some background, how did you import your new Application? Did you use File->Import or New -> Projects->Project from WAR or Ppoject from existing source?

Answer (score 0):

Check the project properties for each of the projects to see what is the source directory for the code set to.